# How to compare numbers in array with resultset?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

Following code compare items user has selected previously with item id's from database and 'checks' those which were selected. So I have a checkbox list of all items where only the ones they previously selected are 'checked'. This is for an update orders page

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open Application("strConn")

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Items"

'current items selected 
'e.g. 31, 32, 33                    
strItemSelected = curr_Item_IDs & ","                                   

set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQL)

If Not rs.EOF Then

Do while not rs.EOF

response.write "<input type = 'checkbox' "

If InStr(strItemSelected, CStr(rs("ID")) & ",") > 0 Then

response.write("checked = 'checked' ")

END if                  

response.write(" name='item' value=""" & rs("ID") & """> " & 
rs("item_name") & vbcrlf)
response.write("/     ID: " & rs("ID") & "<br />")                                          

rs.movenext

Loop

end if

set rs=nothing
```

What this code is doing is with an ID of 31, it selects '31' but also selects '1'. I do think its InStr which is causing the issue, but unsure how to rectify the problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @e4c5 Not helpful, if this was a new project I might agree with you. The likelihood is however that this is an existing project for a system that is well established and the company has not wanted to re-develop it. The reason I say this is I see it all the time and personally have to maintain large scale Classic ASP internal web applications. So yes, Classic ASP is very much alive in this day and age.

Comment: Could you not just do this with a computed column *(binary yes, no or a numeric state etc)* based off a join against the selected items? This would be the approach I would take personally, rather than doing the logic in code yet the RDMS do the work. Entirely depends on your database structure through, whether this is viable.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to adjust your query to include a computed column:

```
'change your query... '
strSQL = "SELECT I.*, case when I.ID in (" & strItemSelected & ") then 'Y' else 'N' end as selected FROM Items I"
```

Then inside your loop, replace your IF with this:

```
If rs("selected") = "Y" Then
    response.write("checked = 'checked' ")
END if
```

If you must do it with the logic in the code and can't change the query, you could use an array instead of trying to make INSTR work...

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open Application("strConn")    
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Items"

'current items selected 
'e.g. 31, 32, 33                    
'-----Create an array here instead of a string------
arrItemSelected = SPLIT(curr_Item_IDs,",")

set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQL)

If Not rs.EOF Then        
    Do while not rs.EOF        
        response.write "<input type = 'checkbox' "
        '----Loop through the array-----
        For i=0 To UBound(arrItemSelected) Step 1
            If arrItemSelected(i) = CStr(rs("ID")) Then
               response.write("checked = 'checked' ")
            END if  
        Next

        response.write(" name='item' value=""" & rs("ID") & """> " & 
        rs("item_name") & vbcrlf)
        response.write("/     ID: " & rs("ID") & "<br />")                                          

        rs.movenext

    Loop
End If
```